# Faster way of selecting sub duplicates in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm trying to filter a dataframe in r, based on the fact that the row entries are the same on the first two out of three columns. What I have done is following (where df is a 3 column dataframe)

```
not_duplicate <- df[!(duplicated(dplyr::select(df, col1, col2))), ]
```

This takes quite some time. Is there a way to speed this up/better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: `df |> dplyr::select(col1, col2) |> dplyr::distinct()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `data.table` option -

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
unique(df, by = c('col1', 'col2'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this make it faster?

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
iris %>% distinct(across(1:2), .keep_all = TRUE) %>% as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 117 x 5
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
#> # … with 107 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

## Speed comparisons

Using `unique` and `data.table` is the fastest way (so far):

```r
library(microbenchmark)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'data.table'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     between, first, last
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     transpose

df <- nycflights13::flights %>% rename(col1 = year, col2 = month)

microbenchmark(
  question = {
    df[!(duplicated(dplyr::select(df, col1, col2))), ]
  },
  Weed = {
    df %>% 
      group_by(col1, col2) %>% 
      mutate(nrep = n()) %>% 
      filter(nrep == 1) %>% 
      ungroup() 
  },
  danlooo = {
    df %>% distinct(across(1:2), .keep_all = TRUE)
  },
  ronak = {
    setDT(df)
    unique(df, by = c('col1', 'col2'))
  },
  times = 10
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval
#>  question  4.059082  4.131558 79.471833  4.211303  6.153801 453.642332    10
#>      Weed 17.702280 19.095162 21.956365 20.565925 26.074310  29.571600    10
#>   danlooo  8.079582  8.133334  9.912199  8.686196  9.827751  15.959280    10
#>     ronak  1.262237  1.386761  1.648035  1.454734  1.572879   3.419493    10
#>  cld
#>    a
#>    a
#>    a
#>    a
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Wow this is great! thanks a ton everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You can subset to *col1* and *col2* using `[`:

```
df[!(duplicated(df[, c("col1", "col2")])),]
```

or using in addition paste:

```
df[!(duplicated(paste(df$col1, df$col2))),]
```

Benchmark:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = rep(letters[1:3], each=4)
               , col2 = rep(letters[1:4], each=3),
                 col3 = rep(letters[1:2], 6))

library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
library(collapse)
library(dplyr)

bench::mark(check = FALSE
          , dplyr = df[!(duplicated(dplyr::select(df, col1, col2))), ]
          , dplyr2 = (df %>% distinct(across(c(col1, col2)), .keep_all = TRUE) %>% as_tibble())
          , base = df[!(duplicated(df[, c("col1", "col2")])),]
          , base2 = df[!(duplicated(paste(df$col1, df$col2))),]
          , dt = unique(dt, by = c('col1', 'col2'))
          , funique = funique(df, cols = c("col1", "col2"))
            )
#  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1 dplyr        1.47ms   1.53ms      647.    6.44KB     14.8   305     7
#2 dplyr2       3.05ms   3.16ms      314.    1.75MB     15.2   145     7
#3 base       105.72µs 112.72µs     8525.        0B     19.0  4039     9
#4 base2       59.55µs  64.29µs    15093.        0B     16.6  7270     8
#5 dt          42.47µs   50.2µs    20178.   92.66KB     12.5  9699     6
#6 funique     18.48µs  20.25µs    47910.   50.81KB     19.2  9996     4
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `funique` from `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
funique(iris, cols = 5)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
2          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
3          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5  virginica
```

---

In the OP's case

```
funique(df, cols = c('col1', 'col2'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
df %>% 
  group_by(col1, col2) %>% 
  mutate(nrep = n()) %>% 
  filter(nrep == 1) %>% 
  ungroup()
```